# Slides disappear when going to the right

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css, swiper.js

I've recently experimented with SwiperJS inside of React but stumbled upon a very annoying problem which I don't know how to solve. I've made a gif to show to problem which afterwards I will put in the code.[image]

This is the code I use

```
        <Swiper
          spaceBetween={10}
          slidesPerView={5}
          speed={500}
          direction={'horizontal'}
          loop={true}
          centeredSlides={true}
          loopedSlides={5}
          roundLengths={true}
          modules={[Navigation]}
          navigation={{
            nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
          }}>
          {skills.map((skill, index) => (
            <SwiperSlide className='flex justify-center align-center '>
              <div className='relative bg-white py-6 px-6 rounded-3xl w-56 my-9 shadow-xl'>
                <div
                  className={` text-white flex items-center absolute rounded-full py-4 px-4 shadow-xl ${skill.color} left-4 -top-6`}>
                  {createElement(skill.icon.type, {
                    className: `w-8 h-8`,
                  })}
                </div>
                <div className='mt-8'>
                  <p className='text-xl font-semibold my-2'>{skill.title}</p>
                  <StarContainer enjoyment={skill.appreciation} />
                </div>
                <div className='border-t-2'></div>
                <div className='font-semibold italic mt-3'>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </SwiperSlide>
          ))}
        </Swiper>
        <div className='swiper-button-prev left-0'></div>
        <div className='swiper-button-next right-0'></div>
      </div>
```

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on v9.2.3 with React. Try to downgrade to v8.4.4 - that helped me.

Source: https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/6451#issuecomment-1501454884